# Blazor component to filter keystrokes

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

Blazor has the `InputNumber` component that constrains input to digits. However that renders an `<input type=number .../>` which firefox does not respect (it permits any text).

So I tried to create a custom component that filters input:

```cs
@inherits InputNumber<int?>

<input type="number" @bind=_value @onkeypress=OnKeypress />
<p>@_value</p>

@code {
  private string _value;

  private void OnKeypress(KeyboardEventArgs e) {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
      _value += e.Key;
  }
}
```

The `<p>` shows the correct value. But the input itself shows all keypresses.

How do I write a custom component to filter keystrokes? (In this example I'm filtering for digits, but I assume the same approach would apply for filtering any char.)

Comment: Keep the old value in memory and when the user adds a character or changes the value into an incorrect value, assign `_value` back to the old value.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine That's what the above code does.

Comment: I was wondering, have you looked with Firefox to see if this a bug? I mean, I upped your question, because I didn't realized this and  fired-up my app in FF and off course, you were right. When I told my team, they asked me if this should be considered a FF bug? I wonder the same, this is pretty straight forward. Input type="number" --> should only allow numbers?!

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug has been open for 5  years, but FF team rejects it saying FF respects the API as it reject inputs internally but it is not showed in the UI... This is sad.

https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/18050

Comment: @Shuryno Yes they say it's intentional but it's obviously a bug. I don't understand why they don't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Blazor EditForm infrastructure you can create a custom `InputNumber`.

The following code inherits from `InputNumber` and makes the following changes.  I've tested it with Firefox and Edge, but don't have Chrome install on my laptop.

1. The input type is changed to `text`.  This ensures consistent behaviour from all browsers - not the case if set to `number.
2. Input `value` is mapped to a new internal field which will update from a new setter.
3. `oninput` is wired to `SetValue` to capture each keypress.
4. `SetValue` contains the new logic to check for valid numeric input.  The code has inline commentary.

```cs
@inherits InputNumber<TValue>
@typeparam TValue

<input type="text"
       value="@this.displayValue"
       class="@this.CssClass"
       @oninput=SetValue
       @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes
       @ref=this.Element />

@code {
    // create a unique string based on the null Ascii char
    //private static string emptyString = ((char)0).ToString();
    private static string emptyString = string.Empty;
    private string? displayValue;

    public async Task SetValue(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current typed value
        var value = e.Value?.ToString();

        // Check if it's a number of the TValue or null
        var isValidNumber = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var num)
            || value is null;

         // If it's not valid we need to reset the value
        if (!isValidNumber)
        {
            // Set the value to an empty string
            displayValue = emptyString;
            // Call state has changed to render the component
            StateHasChanged();
            // Give thw renderer some processor time to execute the queued render by creating a Task continuation
            await Task.Delay(1);
            // Set the display to the previous value stored in CurrentValue 
            displayValue = FormatValueAsString(CurrentValue);
            // done
            return;
        }

        // We have a numbr so set the two fields to the current value
        // This is the display value
        displayValue = value;
        // This triggers the full InputBase/EditContext logic
        CurrentValueAsString = value;
    }
}
```

#### Why we need the Double Render Trick

We have to double render if the number in invalid to fix an inconsistency that occurs between the actual DOM and the Render's DOM.

Consider this:

1. The current value is 12.
2. The Renderer's DOM segment is  `value="12"`.
3. We change the input to `12q`.
4. The browser DOM is now `value="12q"`, while the Renderer DOM is still `value="12"`

If we now set the Renderer DOM to `value="12"` it hasn't changed.  The Diffing engine sees no difference and doesn't update the browser UI.

To solve this we have to make sure the Renderer's DOM is set to something else before we set it to the original value.  We set it to an empty string, give the renderer some processor time with `Task.Delay` to actually render the component and then finally set it back to it's original setting.

Comment: Like another solution here, there is a split second where you can see the dummy empty string as a non-printing char (shows as some weird unicode symbol). I suppose that is unavoidable. This all-c# solution is clever, thanks.

Comment: I have used `string.Empty` in the past as `emptyString`, but was searching for a unique string that doesn't display anything and can't be typed.  If you're getting a strange character then try using `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

<input type="number" value=@_value @oninput=OnInput />
<p>@_value</p>

@code {
    private int oldValue = 50;
    private int _value = 50;

    private async Task OnInput(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        int newValue;
        if(int.TryParse((string)args.Value, out newValue)){
            _value = newValue;
            oldValue = _value;
        }
        else{
            _value = 0;
            await Task.Yield();
            _value = oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is on the 3 lines around `await Task.Yield()` to force the rerender of the input when the characters are wrong.

Be also aware that this solution, as is, will not allow numbers bigger than `Int32.MaxValue` or smaller than `Int32.MinValue`.

**EDIT:**

To avoid showing the value `0` in the input for a split second, we can force the rerender of the full input. However, in Mozilla Firefox it loses focus of the input everytime a forbidden character is written. However, it seems to keep the focus on Chrome.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

@if(rerenderTrick){
    <input type="number" value=@_value/>
}
else{
    <input type="number" value=@_value @oninput=OnInput />
}
<p>@_value</p>

@code {
    private int _value = 50;
    private bool rerenderTrick = false;

    private async Task OnInput(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        int newValue;
        if(int.TryParse((string)args.Value, out newValue)){
            _value = newValue;
        }
        else{
            rerenderTrick = true;
            await Task.Yield();
            rerenderTrick = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. When typing non-digits the UI shows them for a split second and then they disappear. Is that expected?

Comment: Well, it's probably because of the response time. We are kind of rerendering the input twice to get rid of the input of the user. It's not really preventing the non-digits to be written on the input, it is fixing it when it happens.

Comment: @lonix I actually updated my answer to avoid showing 0 for a split second. Did this not fix it for you?

Comment: I didn't know of the update until now... I tried it and it's quite smart. Upvoted and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic numeric component that you can expand and already features the basics that will make this feel like a numeric input, including regex to prevent input that is not allowed.

#### index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<p>
    <label>Integer Value</label>
    <InputNumeric @bind-Value="ValueInteger" DecimalPlaces="0" />
    <span>@ValueInteger</span>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Decimal Value</label>
    <InputNumeric @bind-Value="ValueDecimal" />
    <span>@ValueDecimal</span>
</p>

@code {
    int ValueInteger = 1;
    decimal ValueDecimal = 1;
}
```

#### InputNumeric.razor

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@typeparam T

<input @ref="@ElementReference"
       type="text"
       value="@ValueString"
       @onfocus="FocusEvent"
       @onblur="FormatValue"
       @oninput="ChangeEvent"
       @onchange="ChangeEvent" />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private T _value;

    [Parameter]
    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, value)) return;
            _value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public int DecimalPlaces { get; set; } = 2;

    [Parameter]
    public decimal? Step { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string DisplayFormat { get; set; }

    private string ValueString { get; set; }
    private ElementReference ElementReference { get; set; }
    bool ignoreParameterSet = false;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!ignoreParameterSet)
            FormatValue();

    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyBlazor.SetNumericOnly", ElementReference, DecimalPlaces);
    }

    private void ChangeEvent(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal decimalValue = CastToDecimal(e.Value);

        Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(decimalValue, typeof(T));

        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

    private async void FocusEvent(FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        ignoreParameterSet = true;

        ValueString = Value?.ToString();

        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void FormatValue()
    {
        ignoreParameterSet = false;

        ValueString = String.Format(DisplayFormat ?? $"{{0:N{DecimalPlaces}}}", Value);

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private decimal CastToDecimal(object value) {
        decimal decimalValue;

        var isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(value?.ToString(), out decimalValue);

        if (isDecimal)
        {
            decimalValue = Math.Round(decimalValue, DecimalPlaces);
        }

        return decimalValue;
    }

    private async Task OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "ArrowDown" || e.Code == "ArrowUp")
        {
            var step = Step ?? (DecimalPlaces > 0 ? (decimal).25 : 1);

            decimal decimalValue = CastToDecimal(Value);

            if (e.Code == "ArrowDown")
                decimalValue -= step;

            if (e.Code == "ArrowUp")
                decimalValue += step;

            Value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(decimalValue, typeof(T));

            await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);

            ValueString = Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Javascript:

```
window.MyBlazor = {
    SetNumericOnly: function (element, decimalPlaces) {
        element.oninput = function (i, d) {
            return function (e) {
                var valueNegative = i.value.length > 0 ? i.value[0] == "-" : false;

                i.value = (valueNegative ? "-" : "") + i.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');

                if (d === 0)
                    i.value = i.value.replace('.', '');
            }
        }(element, decimalPlaces);
    }
}
```

#### **Important note:**

This will break on cultures where the decimal separator is anything but `.`. You will need to cater for this.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a very comprehensive solution. If there's no other way I'll use it. But whenever I see a blazor solution with javascript I assume it's because "there's no other way"... is that the case here?

Comment: @lonix, it's about what's more efficient. I have not tried any other way, but I can play around with it in the future and maybe update this post with a pure C# & Blazor solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another javascript solution, which is nice due to its simplicity.

```cs
@inherits InputText

<input
  @bind=CurrentValueAsString
  @bind:event="oninput"
  @attributes=AdditionalAttributes
  class=@CssClass
  onkeypress="return (48 <= event.charCode && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 8"
  onpaste="return false"
  />

@code {
}
```

Placing the javascript inline seems safe as it's always included with the component upon rerendering.

And there are no visual glitches of any kind when using this approach, which is the case with all the c# solutions I've tried.

Comment: I tried it and I was able to write any combination with accent by pressing the accent and then another key, ex: ê, ⁸, Ï, ^, ¨... Probably because they are not written in one key press but two.

Comment: CTRL+V goes through as well.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Nice catch! Updated for onpaste. Accents issue I'm unsure how to handle. Might be good enough for some use cases.